# Radio button clears default values on form reset angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-reactive-forms

I have a reactive form in which there is a radio button group which works on one form variable and it works untill I reset the form. when I reset the form both the radios get deselected.

```
<mat-radio-group aria-label="Select an option" formControlName="IsUnderLc">
   <mat-radio-button value="true" [checked]="workTransactionForm.controls['IsUnderLc'].value == true">
     Under LC
   </mat-radio-button>
   <mat-radio-button value="false[checked]="workTransactionForm.controls['IsUnderLc'].value == false">
     Collection
   </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

I want to keep one selected for which I even tried patching the values back and also giving the default value in FormGroup but nothing works.

```
     this.workTransactionForm.reset();
     this.workTransactionForm.controls.IsUnderLc.setValue(true);
```

Is there any possible way to set values to form controls after resetting the form?

Comment: resetting the form means that all fields will be reset; you can store the state of the radio buttons in localStorage or sessionStorage.. or somewhere in your server-side

Comment: @AkberIqbal I have edited my post, after resetting,How can select the radion button again? So I am just patching the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Could resolve the issue after changing html code 
from

```
<mat-radio-button value="false" [checked]="workTransactionForm.controls['IsUnderLc'].value == false">
     Collection
</mat-radio-button>
```

To

```
<mat-radio-button value="false>
     Collection
</mat-radio-button>
```

And binding it again in .ts file like

```
this.workTransactionForm.controls.IsFresh.patchValue(false);
this.workTransactionForm.controls.IsUnderLc.patchValue(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass (new) values for your form controls in the reset function. This will reset the form and keep/re-add the values you pass.
so you could use:

```
this.workTransactionForm.reset({IsUnderLc: true});
```

Or if you want to keep some values:

```
const currentValue = this.workTransactionForm.get('IsUnderLc').value;
this.workTransactionForm.reset({IsUnderLc: currentValue});
```